# how do you add a style to a blank access 2007 form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

If you create a blank form in access 2007, is there a way to apply a style to that form. So that the blank form can then have the same style as the other already created forms
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an autoformat from one of your existing forms: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102190041033.aspx